# filter with object references lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array, I need to chunk that array & manipulate parts of the chunks BUT I'd like to it to update my original array

I'm self taught with no computer science background so when it comes to technical inner workings I'm at a disadvantage.

```js
var markers = ["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"]

var chunks = _.chunk(markers, 5)
var result = _.chain(chunks[0]).last().value();

result = 'newValue'
console.log(chunks);

console.log(markers);
//was hopping to get
// ["one","two","three","four","newValue","six","seven","eight","nine"]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You only want to change the fifth element in `markers` (`markers[4] = "newValue"`)? Or every fifth element?

Comment: Just one item.  But is it possible to update markers[4] via chunks[0][4]  and have markers[4] updated to the new value of chunks[0][4] automatically ?

Comment: If you only want to change the fifth element there is absolutely no need for `_.chunk \ chunks`

Comment: For me there is. This is a simplified version of my problem. What I actually need to do is chuck the full do a directions api that will give me a new order for each chunk array.  So for instance if I change the order attribute in my chunk[0] items, I'd like that to be reflected in my main array.  Should I just make the updates to each chunk then flatten my chunks array and update the main markers array with it?

Comment: Your current example input and output isn't sufficient to understand what you're trying to do. Can you add more example cases?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I got your requirement right, but this changes the first and last element of each "chunk" (without really splitting the array).

```js
var data = [
    "one","two","three","four","five",
    "one","two","three","four","five",
    "one","two","three"
];

var chunkSize = 5,
    numberOfChunks = Math.ceil(data.length / chunkSize),
    indexOfFirstElementInChunk,
    indexOfLastElementInChunk;

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfChunks; i++) {
    indexOfFirstElementInChunk = (i * chunkSize);
    data[indexOfFirstElementInChunk] = "first element";
  
    indexOfLastElementInChunk = Math.min(data.length, ((i + 1) * chunkSize)) - 1;
    if (indexOfFirstElementInChunk < indexOfLastElementInChunk) {
      data[indexOfLastElementInChunk] = "last element";
    }
}

console.log(data);
```